# jstree disable automatic selection of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using jstree with the checkbox plugin and the "two_state" option.  However, I need to be able to select a parent and NOT have it automatically check that node's children.  I can't merely uncheck all children, because I need to maintain previous selections.  Any ideas?

thanks,

mike

Comment: Could you provide working jsfiddle?